# Topology on closed subsets characterized by sup on continuous functions?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, set-valued-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.  Suppose that $\{A^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of closed, non-empty subsets of $X$.

Is there a Hausdorff topology on the space of closed subsets of $X$, guaranteeing that if $A^n$ converges in this space to a $A\subseteq X$, then for any continuous function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have that
$$
\sup_{x \in A}f(x)\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{x \in A^n}f(x) ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the original version of the problem, with the opposite inequality, is clearly "no": if $X$ contains more than one point then there is no such topology. Let $A^1 = \{x\}$ and $A^n = \{y\}$ for $n \geq 2$, where $x,y \in X$ are distinct. Define $f(z) = d(y,z)$. Since the sequence $(A^n)$ is eventually constant, it must converge to $\{y\}$ for any topology on the space of closed subsets. But the supremum over $\{y\}$ is $0$ and the supremum over $\{x\}$ is $d(x,y) > 0$.

For the revised question, with reversed inequality, the obvious answer is Hausdorff distance. If $A^n \to A$ in Hausdorff distance then for every $x \in A$ and every $k > 0$ there exists $y_k \in A^n$, for some $n$, satisfying $d(x,y_k) \leq \frac{1}{k}$. Thus $y_k \to x$ and so $f(x)$ is $\leq$ the sup of sups.

Comment: Oh my, I had placed the inequality in the wrong direction.  I edited to fix it, sorry about that you're correct, it wasn't the wright question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the edit and very complete answer :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @NikWeaver, since the first sentence only applies to the old version of the problem, maybe it could be deleted and "No" replaced by "No to the original version of the problem (with the opposite inequality)" or similar?

Comment: @LSpice: sure, good idea.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a version of this result that holds when, on the RHS, $f$ is replaces by a sequence of continuous functions from $(X,d)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes if the sequence converges uniformly to $f$, no if you only assume pointwise convergence.

Comment: @NikWeaver  In this case, do we need them to converge uniformly on $(X,d)$ or can we restrict to the limiting set $A$?

Comment: This is a good exercise for you.

Comment: I'll give it a shot then :)